# Using merchant-defined data fields for address line 2 in Authorize.net AIM API

Tags: api, authorize.net

I am building an application that uses the Authorize.net AIM API.

I intend to store the `address` and `address_2` that the user entered on my site in the API call. By default auth.net doesn't provide an address line 2 data field so I wanted to enter a custom field for this and use it to store in the database after I get a response.

In perusing the AIM API documentation I found this clause that concerns me:

> Merchant-defined data fields are not intended to and must not be used
>   to capture personally identifying information. Accordingly, the
>   merchant is prohibited from capturing, obtaining, and/or transmitting
>   any personally identifying information in or by means of the
>   merchant-defined data fields. Personally identifying information
>   includes, but is not limited to, name, address, credit card number,
>   social security number, driver's license number, state issued
>   identification number, passport number, and card verification numbers
>   (CVV, CVC2, CVV2, CID, CVN). If Authorize.Net discovers that the
>   merchant is capturing and/or transmitting personally identifying
>   information by means of the merchant-defined data fields, whether or
>   not intentionally, CyberSource will immediately suspend the merchant's
>   account, which will result in a rejection of any and all transaction
>   requests submitted by the merchant after the point of suspension.

My question is, does this apply in my case? Since the customer is entering it on my own site I'm not technically getting this information from auth.net.

If anyone has any experience with this I would appreciate a pointer. it wouldn't break my heart to work around this issue, except that I would like it to be as clean as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the data before sending to Authorize.Net, you may wish to save the information to the DB yourself instead of trying to pass potentially sensitive data round trip through the gateway.

Comment: Sensible solution. The only trouble with that is I have a method that does the call and a method that handles the response. When I get the response is where the DB logging happens. I wouldn't want to make a special call just to add this little bit of data.